# What are the macros #[pallet::genesis_config] and #[pallet::genesis_build] doing on the sudo pallet?

Tags: substrate

```rust
#[pallet::genesis_config]
    pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
        /// The `AccountId` of the sudo key.
        pub key: T::AccountId,
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "std")]
    impl<T: Config> Default for GenesisConfig<T> {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self { key: Default::default() }
        }
    }

    #[pallet::genesis_build]
    impl<T: Config> GenesisBuild<T> for GenesisConfig<T> {
        fn build(&self) {
            <Key<T>>::put(&self.key);
        }
    }
```

What is happening here with `genesis_config` and `genesis_build` macros here? Some reading seemed to suggest that implement the trait [GenesisBuild<T,I = ()>](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/traits/trait.GenesisBuild.html) but I am confused as the docs read: "`T` and `I` are placeholder for pallet trait and pallet instance."

What are pallet instances? I also assume pallet trait means the `Config` trait for the sudo pallet. Is it some how related to configuring a unique `StorageValue` for the Genesis block so that each instance of a running node can verify that the same Account is Root? Can someone help break it down for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#[pallet::genesis_build]` implements the trait `sp_runtime::BuildModuleGenesisStorage` which puts the initial state into the pallet's storage at genesis time.
(The pallet can put state into child storage also at that point.)

The pub enum/struct with `#[pallet::genesis_config]` holds the fields that genesis_build reads in order to set up the storage. For example there may be investors at genesis that need a vesting schedule set up (See the vesting pallet: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3cdb30e1ecbafe8a866317d4550c921b4d686869/frame/vesting/src/lib.rs#L231 ). So for the sudo pallet, the genesis_config struct holds the root key which is set here:

```rust
GenesisConfig {
        sudo: SudoConfig {
            // Assign network admin rights.
            key: root_key,
        },
        ...
}
```

( https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3cdb30e1ecbafe8a866317d4550c921b4d686869/bin/node-template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L150 )

Docs for genesis_config are here: https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#genesis-config-palletgenesis_config-optional

Answer (score 7):

> What are pallet instances?

Pallets can be made instantiable. This means a Pallet can be used multiple times in a runtime. Each instance will use the same code (modulo different configuration through the configuration trait), but the storage will be different for each instance.

See: https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/basics/instantiable-pallets/

> I also assume pallet trait means the Config trait for the sudo pallet. Is it some how related to configuring a unique StorageValue for the Genesis block so that each instance of a running node can verify that the same Account is Root? Can someone help break it down for me.

Yes Pallet trait means the `Config` trait.

The point here with `GenesisBuild` taking two generic arguments is to support all kinds of Pallets. Every Pallet is configurable through the trait, so the `GenesisBuild` trait needs to take the `Config` generic parameter `T`. Some Pallets can be instantiable, so it also needs to take `I`.

This all boils down to some Rust "quirks" to support instantiable Pallets that are using the default instance and custom instances and also to support Pallets that don't use any instancing at all.

Comment: I appreciate the insights, but I feel that my main question still revolves around what #[pallet::genesis_build] and #[pallet::genesis_config] do, so if you can add that, would make the answer complete.

Comment: `genesis_config` just tells the "outer" `pallet` macro what the genesis config type is. Not that much else. And `genesis_build` is doing something similar, it tells the macro that this trait is being implemented. You can not do type resolving in macros, so you don't know if a trait is implemented for example because it could have been renamed locally. So, you "hint" the macro this information.